# What shortcuts for Intellij from VS code for toggle side bar visability and quick open

Tags: intellij-idea, visual-studio-code, shortcut, hotkeys

Recently had to work in VS code and found some useful shortcuts like `Ctrl+B`(Toggle Side Bar Visibility) opens left side project hierarchy and `Ctrl+P`(quick find) search field for finding files in projects. I would like to use those hotkeys in Intellij too, but can't find them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd> to toggle the Project View tool window. <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd> for Search Everywhere or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd> for files only.

Related documentation:

- https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/manipulating-the-tool-windows.html
- https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/searching-everywhere.html

Comment: Yea, it's exactly those shortcuts I needed, I thought Intellij may do not have them. Thank you.